# Access - How to display cascading dropdown values on table as a part of result data

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have 2 cascading dropdown boxes (A, B) on access form. When select the value for dropdown A, dropdown B will get loaded based on the value of dropdown A. Once I select value for dropdown B, the table underneath these two dropdowns display data with 6 different columns. I also want to display value for dropdown A and dropdown B in the table. But somehow the values for both dropdown doesn't display on table. Seems like both dropdowns are hidden on the page. I don't know how to resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because of your settings on the dropdown? Have you deactivated scrolling and/or made your number of entries in the dropdown to be less than the number of items in the list?

Comment: i have created another ticket for this. please see my issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249927/access-link-child-fields-value-automatically-hidden-how-to-unhide-it